# android mobile control

Tags: android, admin, device

I don't want to do advertisement but sample app for behavior of my application is ESET antivirus.

One requested feature of my application is that for uninstall is needed password. I add my app to device admin list and it is not possible to uninstall it now. But you can Deactive app as admin device. Whan you go to Settings > Location & security > Select device administrators and you try to deactive ESET Security it starts the activity (I guess from  DeviceAdminReceiver.onDisableRequested()) which is waiting for password and your mobile is locked. Home button, back button and even SwitchOff button doesn't react=>

How it is possible that Home,Back,SwitchOff and Camera button doesn't react?

EDIT - second question removed
(After I took out battery from my phone - ESET wasn't device admin too)

Thank you for ideas.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out these security issues in Android. Normally, you would do this by sending an email to security@android.com rather than by posting it in places like StackOverflow. Ordinary SDK apps should not be able to do what you cite here, and I will spend some time determining how this is occurring to make sure that it is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, sorry ESET but this feature looks very interesting so I took a look at decompiled sources  :)

The basic workflow is the following:

- `com.eset.ems.antitheft.receiver.AdminReceiver` subclass of `DeviceAdminReceiver` is registered for broadcast actions `DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED` and `DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED`
- When device admin is disabled `com.eset.ems.antitheft.receiver.AdminReceiver.onDisabled()` is called
- `com.eset.ems.antitheft.LockActivity` is started from the `AdminReceiver.onDisabled()`
- `LockActivity` shows `com.eset.ems.antitheft.LockingDialog` where the most blocking magic happens

As for the Home and other button block antivirus do the following trick - it uses [ActivityManagerNative](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityManagerNative.java) from Android internals. To keep `LockActivity` at the top of all other activities it starts a thread which contsantly calls `ActivityManagerNative.moveTaskToFront()` with `LockActivity` task ID. Prior to API level 10 reflection is used to access hidden `moveTaskToFront()` from [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) class and after API 10 it just uses `ActivityManagerNative` code from Android codebase to access it.
Also both `LockActivity` and `LockingDialog` call `ActivityManagerNative.closeSystemDialogs()` method many times. Probably this is done in order to cancel system dialog which arises after power button long press.

As for the stopping execution of `DeviceAdminReceiver.onDisableRequested` actually I didn't notice anything special about it in the code. It only starts the activity after device admin is disabled and that's all. And on my phone device admin was disabled after I took the battery out.

Comment: I was happy to give you my points. Thank you. The only and useful answer after 7 month. Now I will try to achieve this with your findings. How did you find out how it works? Can I ask you later for some additional info?

Comment: Thank you for the great question. I used dex2jar (https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) tool to convert classes.dex file extracted from the ESET antivirus apk. It produces regular jar file that can be viewered with any decompiler (particularly I use JD from http://java.decompiler.free.fr/, probably the best free Java decompiler). Actually that's all, after that I had source code files and could see how it works. I just noticed from the logcat that LockActivity is being launched when I disable device admin for the ESET antivirus and took it as a start point.

Comment: @AndreiMankevich Can you please look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282857/device-admin-confirm-before-deactivate and suggest me your thoughts about it ?