# Device admin confirm before DEACTIVATE

Tags: android, security, settings, admin, device

I want to ask a confirmation before disabling/deactivating device admin for my application. I searched a lot about it but not fing any proper solution for this.

In short, I want to detect a callback when user click DEACTIVATE button from device admin and I want to ask a confirmation to use that whether are you sure you want to deactivate device admin ? If use press cancel then device admin should not be deactivated.

**If you observer  AppLock application by DoMobile Lab from google play store, you can find that this app is doing the same thing. So there must be some secret behind it.**

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by overriding [onDisableRequested()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html#onDisableRequested(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)) method of DeviceAdminReceiver

```
public class AdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
    @Override
    public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {
        return "Are you sure you want to disable the Device admin?";//OR whatever message you would like to display
    }

}
```

As per documentation

> Called when the user has asked to disable the administrator, as a result of receiving ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED, giving you a chance to present a warning message to them. The message is returned as the result; if null is returned (the default implementation), no message will be displayed.

This will show a popup with OK and cancel button, along with the text returned.